# RecyclerView with Images blocking the UI

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso

I have a recyclerview that loads a set of items which mainly display an image. I retrieve this items in the background, in batches of 100. I load the images using Picasso. Images are quite big, but I resize them using fit().

Whenever the screen is loaded or refreshed using SwipeRefreshLayout, the UI blocks for less than a second, but enough to be noticeable. If I dont load the images but put just the text, then the UI block does not happen.

I put logging lines on Picasso and on every refresh the 100 images are retrieved, but I would guess Picasso is working in a background thread?

Adapter:

```
@ActivityScope
class LimitableListAdapter @Inject constructor() : RecyclerView.Adapter<LimitableListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var events: MutableList<Event> = mutableListOf()
    private var itemClick: ((Event, View) -> Unit)? = null


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val binding : ItemVideoGridScoreBinding = holder.binding

        var viewModel = binding.viewModel
        val event = events[position]

        //Unbind old viewModel if we have one
        viewModel?.unbind()

        // Create new ViewModel, set it, and bind it
        viewModel = EventViewModel(event)
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        viewModel.bind()


        holder.setClickListener(itemClick)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = events.size


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<ItemVideoGridScoreBinding>(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                R.layout.item_video_grid_score,
                parent,
                false
        )
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }


    fun updateEvents(events: List<Event>, stride: Int) {
        var size = this.events.size
        Timber.w("Updating with: " + events.joinToString(",", transform = { e -> e.id.toString() }))
        this.events = events.toMutableList()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
        /*if (size == 0) {
            Timber.w("branch 1")
            var mutableList = events.toMutableList()
            if(mutableList.size == 0)
                return
            mutableList.add(Event.mockEvent(stride))
            this.events.addAll(mutableList)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        } else {
            if (size > 2) {
                Timber.w("branch 2.1")
                this.events.addAll(size - 1, events.toMutableList())
                notifyItemRangeChanged(size-1, events.size)
            }
            else {
                Timber.w("branch 2.2")
                this.events.addAll(size, events.toMutableList())
                notifyItemRangeChanged(size, events.size)
            }

        }*/
        Timber.i("New list is: " +  this.events.joinToString(",", transform = { e -> e.id.toString() }))
    }

    fun clearList(){
        this.events.clear()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun setClickListener(itemClick: ((Event, View) -> Unit)?) {
        this.itemClick = itemClick
    }


    class ViewHolder(val binding: ItemVideoGridScoreBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun setClickListener(callback: ((Event, View) -> Unit)?) {
            binding.viewModel.clicks().subscribe() {
                callback?.invoke(binding.viewModel.event, itemView)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

BindingUtils:

```
@BindingAdapter({"app:coverUrl"})
    public static void loadCover(ImageView view, String imageUrl) {

            Picasso p = Picasso.with(view
                    .getContext());
                    p.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);

                    p.load(imageUrl)
                    .fit()
                    .centerInside()
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_broken_image)
                    .into(view);
        }
    }
```

xml:

```
(...)
     <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/event_cover"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:coverUrl="@{videoItem.cover}"
                    tools:src="@drawable/img"
                    />
(...)
```

Comment: put your adapter code

Comment: @diegoveloper posted

Comment: retrieving 100 images at the same time and notify ui is a heavy work. also i don't think that you're showing all these images at the same time. so you can consider to implement pagination.

Comment: UI blocking happens even with 20 per page...

Comment: replace Picasso with Glide Glide is more fast and efficient than Picasso. Glide performance comparison goes here.  https://medium.com/@multidots/glide-vs-picasso-930eed42b81d  Check out if the performance is improved or not.

Comment: Please, add `onRefresh()` code

Comment: Post code for "viewModel.bind()" and your XML with the RecyclerView please

Comment: Are you using multiple recyclerviews?

Comment: Did you set `recyclerview.setNestedScrollenable(false)`?

Comment: @Bek how does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are not able to create thumbnails on the server side (which would be the easiest solution), my suggestion would be to go with one of the following

1. Using a local drawable as a Placeholder. This will not block the UI thread and the image can load in the background. Behaviour will be similar to how Instagram behaves when you load the grid of images. Something like below.

`p.load(imageurl).placeholder(R.drawable.localFile).fit().centerInside().error(R.drawable.ic_broken_image).into(view)`

2. Use Glide. Glide does have powerful capability to create Thumbnails. And you can load the Thumbnails into the view much faster than the full images.

Comment: Ended up doing this. Glide is indeed much faster than Picasso

Answer (score 1):

Resizing several big images takes some time. While Picasso does caching over the resized images, the first time it will still need to resize every one (and subsequent times it will just use the resized ones on the cache, thus taking less time).
Also, using `fit` can take more time than just using `resize` because it needs to calculate the size depending on the layout. If you can calculate the static size yourself (just once) and then use `resize` it should improve loading times.

But most of the times, it would be better if your server could send you smaller images/thumbnails when previewing, and then a full size image if you want to see it on some detail screen.

Comment: this helped a lot but Picasso still struggled, Glide was an improvement!

Answer (score 0):

As you are loading 100 images and as you mentioned images are big, 
so it will block the UI Thread for sure, if you want to avoid this so You can `resize` the images with Picasso:

```
Picasso.with(context)
        .load(-yourImgURL-)
        .resize(450, 200) // resizes image to desired dimensions here
        .into(-yourImageView);
```

Comment: Thanks, as you can see in my code snippet I am using fit which effectively resizes the images.